# Help with nodes in drupal

Tags: drupal

I have been tasked with updating a drupal site. I have a link like this site.com/node/28 which lists stories. Where does the 28 come from, I have been all over the admin and there is nothing with that number there. How do i find that page and edit it?

Comment: may be you should post this question in new stackexchange site [drupal answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 28 is the node id (nid).  If you have the correct administrator privileges, you should see a tab at the top of the node titled 'Edit' on at that url.  You can also try going to 'site.com/node/28/edit' to edit the node.

If you see an "Access Denied" message when trying to access that url, you will need to be given more permissions to edit the node.

For a better general understanding of Drupal see http://drupal.org/getting-started
and to learn more about administering Drupal see http://drupal.org/documentation/administer

Comment: When I go to edit, it just presents me with a blank form, like the page has not been created yet. When viewing the page it lists out all stories. There isn't an edit link on the page. It seems to be an automatically generated page.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of what you are seeing on the view/edit screens?  It could be a module that is causing this, or could be custom code that is defining the content to display on the node. It is hard to tell without more information

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing a list, it's most likely coming from a Views block, which will be added to the page in the blocks admin section at admin/build/block, with the content of the view actually configured in the Views admin section at admin/build/views.